# How to add custom zoom in magento 1.9.3.0

Tags: magento-1.9, zoom

i've customized media.phtml to get all images in a grid of one column:
but in mouse hover only the base image is showed in zoom.
this is my code : 
  [image]

Comment: Please put your code as text here so we can copy easier.